# Images not found in textureregion

Tags: android, textures, libgdx, texture-atlas

Previously I was using simple `Texture` for sprite based animations, but that did not provide support for images which were not in the power of 2. [TexturePacker](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/TexturePacker) provides with the ability to load all the images at once, and then fetch the required image from an `imageatlas`.

That said, I followed a couple of tutorials from the Libgdx wiki and it works well till the loading part. But I suppose during rendering, it is causing some problem. This is how I am loading the images into the `texturepacker` in my desktop project:

```
private static final String INPUT_DIR = "../Drop-Android/assets/images";
    private static final String OUTPUT_DIR = "../Drop-Android/assets/image-atlases";
    private static final String PACK_FILE = "pages-info";
    public static void main(String[] args){
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.title = "Drop";
        cfg.width = 800;
        cfg.height = 480;

        Settings settings = new Settings();
        settings.maxWidth = 512;
        settings.maxHeight = 512;
        TexturePacker2.process(settings, INPUT_DIR, OUTPUT_DIR, PACK_FILE);
        new LwjglApplication(new Drop(), cfg);
    }
```

**Question**: Do I have to create `pages-info` i.e. the `PACK_FILE` manually in the images-atlases folder? If I do not, it throws `File not found exception`.

I happen to create `pages-info` file in the `image-atlases` folder and the following files are generated: `pages-info.png` and 'pages-info.atlas'. While, `pages-info` files is empty, the `.png` and `.atlas` files have the images and JSON image data, respectively.

This is what I am using to extract the `textureregions` out of the `pages-info` file (which is empty):

```
TextureAtlas ta = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("image-atlases/pages-info"));
        imageOneRegion = ta.findRegion("image1.png");
        imageTwoRegion = ta.findRegion("image2.png");
```

As expected, it returns a `nullpointerexception` when drawing the `textureregion`. I am running out of ideas here, any help and ideas?

Comment: unless you named your image( also the region name ) image.png.png it you omit the extention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The textures are named as in the `.pack` file, without extensions. Try using `"image1"` instead of `"image1.png"`.

If you watch your `ta` variable using the debug tool you should be able to see the names of textures actually loaded.